# How to make fontsize bigger for one letter in matlab plot title

Tags: matlab

I want to make `\mu` to appear the same size as the other letters, how can i do that?

```
title('Größen-Parameter x in dem spongiösen Knochen(300\mum, 600\mum und 2000\mum)');
```

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question in the title:

You can adjust the font size of a letter (or a text of any length) with `{\fontsize{size},letter}`. E.g.:

```
title('Größen-Parameter x in dem spongiösen Knochen(300{\fontsize{14}\mu}m, 600{\fontsize{14}\mu}m und 2000{\fontsize{14}\mu}m)');
```

However, your actual problem seems to be that the mu's appear slightly smaller than the rest of the text. The reason for this is that Matlab by default interprets normal text as literal characters ([WYSIWYG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG)) while using a latex interpreter if you call a latex command such as `\mu`. This causes those letters to be displayed differently.

Of course you can just increase the size of those letters, but that's not very elegant and the letters will still have a different style. As an alternative I would suggest using a Latex interpreter for the whole text - aside from solving your problem, it will also look nicer!

```
title('Groessen-Parameter x in dem spongioesen Knochen (300 $\mu$m, 600 $\mu$m und 2000 $\mu$m)','interpreter','latex');
```

The only problem are your german special characters (ö and that double s thingy). To display those correctly you would have to load the german language package `ngerman`. This isn't easy but there are instructions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98760/including-package-to-create-matlab-labels-using-latex). However, if you are using a german matlab (if that's a thing) it might work without that.

Comment: thank you, it works and saved me sooo much time, i googled and found nothing to this.

Comment: No problem! Check out the updated version of the upper line of code, I simplified it.